# Which of my two examples is right, based on Clean Code principles?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, coding-style, clean-architecture

I know some people will say it's a based opinion question but I really don't think so, since it's a convention already but I'm missing something.

I'm trying to understand better the Clean Code way of coding and sometimes I just get confused about the right approach.

I'll use as example, the Auto Login with AD on a system. 
The rule says: A user can LogIn on system using the AD account. If he is not "allowed" yet to use the system, we have to check a parameter on the settings. If the parameter says AutoCreation TRUE, we create a new credential and allow him to login.

Ok, said that, here comes the code:

```
// WE HAVE CODE HERE
var userInfo = GetUserInfo(request);
if (userInfo == null)
{
    if (IsAutoUserCreationSettingsEnabled())
        userInfo = AutoCreateUser(request);
}
//AND WE HAVE MORE CODE HERE
```

The method GetUserInfo has just a call to the Data Layer and returned the found user.
If the user is NULL, we now call the other method to check the IsAutoUserCreationSettingsEnabled, which identifies if the AutoCreate is true or false and if true, create the user on database.

It's looks ok, but since my method (the main method) has more rules, the function with 5 lines is impossible.
So, I was thinking if the correct way isn't put on the GetUserInfo method all the details to get the user. So the main method will be:

```
// WE HAVE CODE HERE
var userInfo = GetUserInfo(request);
//AND WE HAVE MORE CODE HERE
```

And the

```
//Get the user from database and more CODE
if (userInfo == null)
{
    if (IsAutoUserCreationSettingsEnabled())
        userInfo = AutoCreateUser(request);
}
//more CODE
```

goes inside the GetUserInfo.
But I feel like the GetUserInfo(AndCreateUser) method now has 2 responsabilities and it's wrong.

So now I'm confused about how it really should work.
What is the right or better way to be a clean coder?

Thanks in advance guys.

** EDIT **

Changed the method GetUserAutoCreationStatus() name and usage.

Just saying, the AutoCreateUser method creates generic data for some fields and create the user on database. The user will change the generic data with his data on next access.

** EDIT² **

Based on @BionicCode comment, I guess the right away should be this one:

```
private void AFewLinesBefore()
{       
  AFewCodeLinesBefore();
  ValidateRequisites(request);
  var userInfo = GetValidUserInfo(request);  
  AFewCodeLinesAfter();
}
```

and on my GetValidUserInfo, I should have this:

```
private UserInfo GetValidUserInfo(LogInUserWithADRequest request)
{
    var userInfo = GetUserInfo(request); 

    if (userInfo == null)
    {
        if (IsAutoUserCreationSettingsEnabled())
        {
            userInfo = AutoCreateUser(request);
        }
    }
    return userInfo;
}

private void AFewCodeLinesBefore()
{
    ...
}

private void AFewCodeLinesAfter()
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: You could have a `GetOrCreateUser` method that handles that whole thing and still have just `GetUser` when you don't need to create the user.

Comment: This looks like a better fit for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com). If `GetAutoUserCreationStatus` tells you whether auto user creation is enabled, why not change the method name to that? Then you don't need the variable to make it clear what the method call does. Generally speaking, if I came across this code I'd find it easy to understand. Some code just sets off alarms. This doesn't.

Comment: @juharr thanks for collaborating but a method can't have Or, If and And on it's names, following the Clean Code book by Uncle Bob. If it have one of those words, the method probably has two responsabilities.

Comment: @ScottHannen you mean removing the variable and put the method inside the if? Like If (GetAutoUserCreationStatus())?

Comment: Exactly. From the usage someone could probably infer what the method does. But if "get auto user creation status" really means "users that don't exist are auto created" then it's not a great method name. If we ever find ourselves saying, "When I say this, I mean that," then why not just say that instead?

Comment: Don't move code between methods. When you want to reduce line count of a method extract lines to a new Method. You design methods by responsibility and abstraction level like having high level methods that use more specialized low level operations. In your case you should introduce a new method called `GetValidUserInfo()`. This method wraps the calls to `GetUserInfo` and the handling of `AutoCreateUser()`. This way you can reduce the size of a method and encapsulate responsibility and behavior. Just select the related lines of code and extract them into a new method with a descriptive name.

Comment: Thanks @BionicCode, it makes sense to me. Can you write an answer?

Comment: Answering your question is not possible any more since some busy people closed your thread by marking it _"as too broad"_. I am sorry.

Comment: @BionicCode I edited my question with what I understood from you. If I understood it wrong, please, let me know!

Comment: Yes. That's basically what I meant. You can continue to extract code (from the extracted method) to a new method until it is not possible anymore (or doesn't make sense). This way your code becomes more readable since you split one general method with a general name into several specialized methods that do a very specific job and therefore have a very specific name.

Comment: It's recursive: extract code to a new method. From this new method extract code to a new method. ...

Comment: Next step, refactor `GetValidUserInfo` e.g. Put `// a few lines here to call the db layer and get the userInfo` into a dedicated method and also put `//a few lines here to create the user with generic data // and fill the userInfo instance with this new one` into another method.

Comment: Check your last edit, please

Comment: Sorry for the delay @BionicCode and yeah!! It's exactly what I did. I'm trying to keep my code always around 5 lines, so, I keep extracting methods until reach this goal. Thanks a lot, I really appreciatte your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell both methods get some info for the user and I'm guessing the class they are in is some kind of authorize user type of class. So, as far as i would think about single responsibility is that the AutoCreateUser function should be in a user creation class, and the rest is fine if the class they are in is some sort of authorization class.

Comment: At this moment we are creating the User. The autocreation method calls the datalayer for this AD user (since it isn't on our system database).